# Kernel issues on ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: boot, drivers, 18.04, kernel

I'm not a pro about linux/ubuntu and Kernel but i will try to be the more precise possible.

Here's my problem :

I've a Dell Inspiron 7591 2n1 and I've installed ubuntu 18.04.3 (LTS), i'm using the kernel version 4.15.0.45.48 to boot.

The problem is that I don't have any drivers (graphics, touchpad, wifi, bluetooth, sound, ....).

I find out that maybe it can come from the fact that the kernel version isn't the good one so I've installed UKUU and installed the versions 5.3.15 and 5.4.2 but none of them boot and I get the error of the picture attached.

[trying to boot on v5.4.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubNnc.jpg)
[image]

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't have any drivers (graphics, touchpad, wifi, bluetooth, sound, ....)"?

Comment: Like I can't use another screen to extend my desk, there is no sound when i play a vidéo and if i don't use an eternal wifi card (usb Netgear) I can't have wifi.

Comment: I suggest to ask a separate question regarding each problem with detailed explanation of each problem. I guess you need to install audio codecs and probably graphics drivers.

Comment: Okay I see but when I dig to find some answers for why when I launch ubuntu software and upgrade program i see almost nothing in aditionnal drivers it was recommanded to upgrade my kernel version and those kind of problems will be remove. I you still think that i need to separate into specifics posts for each I'll do it.

Comment: Remove all unsupported mainline kernels and ask specific questions. These issues should be solved different ways.